# How to Restart/Start Windows command File from an other Command file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

```
I have a command file running 24*7 , sometimes , this is stopped and requires
```

manual intervention to  restart the command file. Can i do this with other command file(job) file monitoring.

```
 " IF my .cmd is not running for <5mins , start again ? " ,
   IF so How can this be achieved?    


How can this be done using windows batch file.



    Algorithm,

     IF (Test.cmd is not running and sleep_time <(5*60) ) 
        { Start Test.cmd }
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that if your cmd file is not running for longer than 5 minutes then ignore it?

Comment: Then start the command file again( In my example " Test.cmd"

Comment: It would help to know which executable is running to be able to check via tasklist.  Which version of Windows is this for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
@echo off
Set MyProcess=Notepad.exe

:test
tasklist | find /i "%MyProcess%">nul  && Taskkill /F/IM  "%MyProcess%" || start "%MyProcess%"
timeout 300 /nobreak
goto:test
```